# How to trigger a function on number of consecutive clicks in any order?

Tags: php, jquery, css

```
 <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#div1').click(function(){
    $('#div3').click(function(){
     $('#div3').click(function(){
      setTimeout( function() { $('.img1').hide();$('.img2').hide(); }
        , 500 );
          $('.img3').show(); 
     }); 
     });
    });
   });
 </script>
```

after clicking three div`s consecutively, the function should get invoked. 
How  clicks can be performed in any order?

Comment: You need some kind of variable that is increased on div click and decreased outside it (body click)

Comment: what you tried? pls explain it briefly? what div1,div2 and div3 suppose to do?

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: I've three divs which are rather images. after I finished with clicking on all of them in any order, something will happen(eg. a div which is already visible gets hidden.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var clicks = {};

$('#div1').click(function(){
  clicks.div1 = true;
  allClicked();
});
$('#div2').click(function(){
  clicks.div2 = true;
  allClicked();
});
$('#div3').click(function(){
  clicks.div3 = true;
  allClicked();
});

function allClicked() {
  if (!clicks.div1 || !clicks.div2 || !clicks.div3) {
    // not yet 
    return;
  }

  // do something because here are all clicked
}
```

Comment: while this would work, I would personally do `function allClicked() { if (clicks.div1 && clicks.div2 && clicks.div3) { /* do stuff */} else return false; }` as I feel it's clearer to read for others. Also, this way you get a return value to know if stuff happened.

Comment: Well I am an advocate of the guard clause, but that is pure philosophy and up to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I write for you a possible solution. Let me know it was helpful for you. Here you have [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ws7NQ/13/). I suggest to use a single eventListener. ex: `$("#container")`. where we have that divs.